# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed

Tags: django, mongodb

i am trying to use MongoDB data base in django. For that i changed my setting to this I am using mlab here.

> settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'crud-django',
        'HOST': 'mongodb://adityakmr:password1@ds231956.mlab.com:31956/',
        'USER': 'adityakmr',
        'PASSWORD': 'password1'
    }
}
```

But everytime i try to run migrations i got some error like this. I have no idea where it is comming from i have already provided correct user name and password.
I have also installed djongo using pip.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 87, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 48, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 43, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\introspection.py", line 46, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.collection_names(False)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 715, in collection_names
    nameOnly=True, **kws)]
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 674, in list_collections
    read_pref) as (sock_info, slave_okay):
  File "c:\users\adity\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1101, in _socket_for_reads
    with self._get_socket(server) as sock_info:
  File "c:\users\adity\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1058, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(self.__all_credentials) as sock_info:
  File "c:\users\adity\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 1006, in get_socket
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 677, in check_auth
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 563, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 540, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-1')
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 262, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 579, in command
    unacknowledged=unacknowledged)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 150, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\crud-django\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Is you mongo database password is correct with provided credentials?

Comment: yes, the password is correct I have checked thrice.

Comment: Try this `DATABASES = {{
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'AUTH_SOURCE': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': '<username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': '<code>.mlab.com',
        'PORT': <port>,
        'ENGINE': 'djongo'
    }
}}`

Comment: what should i put in AUTH_SOURCE  ?

Comment: Your db name, the db use for django project. make sure you can correct this db with your username and password

Comment: @ShafikurRahman Thank you this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest version use client to connect to DB.
I hope following DB configuration will resolve your issue.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
        'LOGGING': {
            'version': 1,
            'loggers': {
                'djongo': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'propogate': False,                        
                }
            },
         },
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': '127.0.0.1',
            'port': 27017,
            'username': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
            'password': "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            'authSource': 'admin',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that not work! 
``` django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use USERNAME instead USER

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'test_db',
        'USERNAME': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': 27017,
        'AUTH_SOURCE': 'test_db',
    }
}`